# Read a word in a given position from every line in a text file using shell script

Tags: scripting, file-handling

I want to read a specific word (say positioned second) of every line from the text file using Shell script. I would prefer shell scripting as it is easier for me to implement the rest of the functions easily. I'm currently stuck on extracting the second word from the text file one by one so that I can use that word to search for the files that contain it. Since I'm  new to this I haven't tried much.

The code that I have tried is this.

```
SETLOCAL
(FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,2) DO SET /P line=) < sql.txt
> another.txt ECHO %line%
ENDLOCAL
```

I ran it using powershell in Windows cmd but it says the `<` operator is reserved for future use.

Comment: Please show us your code (not just the line you can't write as you are stuck on it) and what you have written so far and then the part where you are stuck.

Comment: As this site is not intended for "here's my problem, write my code" :)

Comment: Also think how you can make this as general as possible so it help other people.  Questions that are overly specific to 1 person are likely to be closed.

Comment: And sorry for the mistakes,M kinda new to this.@MichaelDurrant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this didn't *just work* in PowerShell is that Shell code won't run in PS, pretty much.  You can use most DOS commands in PowerShell, but the ol' Shell approach of FOR % etc and things like that?  No go.

The reason they don't work is that PowerShell introduces new and very powerful ways of doing things you could do in shell code/batch and normally with much less code.  In addition, the PowerShell code approach to a process will generally be much easier to read and understand.  So, after this preamble, here is how you do it in PowerShell:

I created six text files, here's a listing of what they contain:

```
so this is the
so is is the
so the is the
so word is the
so I is the
so want is the
```

As you can see, if you read the second word, this makes sense.  What we can do in PowerShell is run the DIR command to get a listing of the files in this directory, then send that on to the Get-Content cmdlet--the modern equivalent of type.exe--which will read the text file.  We can then .Split on the space character, and select the second word from each line.

The completed code looks like this:

```
dir | ForEach { (get-content -Path $_.FullName).split()[1]}
```

The general flow of PowerShell is that the output of one command becomes the input of another, when you use the '|' pipe character.  So what's happening in this example is that:

- we're running DIR, which gives us a listing of files.
- We send that on to the ForEach cmdlet, which will run a given
  {scriptblock} of code once for each item in the list, substituting
  the item's properties in for the $_ character.
- We use that to run Get-Content, listing the contents of the file
- We then use PowerShell's .Split method to split on the space and then
- select the second item using [1].

Why the number 1 instead of two?  PowerShell arrays begin at zero, meaning that 1=2nd item in the list.  Running that command in my directory gives this as the results:

```
this
is
the
word
I
want
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity i entered all the lines in one single text file and tried to do the same operation by replacing -Path $_.FullName with my file name.In the result I just got the the second line of the text file repeating for some 25 times. where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Ah, my approach is to grab the second word out of each file, assuming they all have one line each.  With a multi lined file, the code changes slightly.

If you want to grab the word out of every line in One file: 

    `Get-Content .\stackOneFile.txt | ForEach { $_.Split()[1]}`

If you want to grab the second work from every line in every file in a directory (in my example. I've got two files named stack, each containing all of the lines from my earlier six files):

    `dir stack* | ForEach { Get-Content $_ | ForEach { $_.Split()[1]} }`

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use bash shell

```
     filename="$1"
      while read -r line
       do
        echo "$line" | awk '{print $2}' 
       done < "$filename"
```